# Run command when vim enters visual mode

Tags: triggers, vim

I use a little script to trigger insert modes in order to change the line number color:

```
function! CursorLineNrColorInsert(mode)
    " Insert mode: blue
    if a:mode == "i"
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=4
        highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#268bd2

    " Replace mode: red
    elseif a:mode == "r"
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=1
        highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#dc322f

    else
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=0
        highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#073642

    endif
endfunction

autocmd InsertEnter * call CursorLineNrColorInsert(v:insertmode)
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=0
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#073642
```

That works pretty fine and changes my line number **instantly** when I enter any insert mode and reverts back to the original color in normal mode.

I would like to do the same for the visual mode:

```
function! CursorLineNrColorVisual(mode)
    " Visual mode: orange
    if mode()=~#"^[vV\<C-v>]"
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=9
        highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#cb4b16

    else
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=0
        highlight CursorLineNr guifg=#073642

    endif
endfunction

autocmd CursorMoved * call CursorLineNrColorVisual(mode())
```

Basically that works but **not instantly** since the function is triggered on `CursorMoved`. How could I fire `CursorLineNrColorVisual()` **instantly** as soon as I would activate any visual mode?

Comment: There is no `VisualEnter` or `VisualLeave` event. What about mapping `v`, `V` and `<C-v>` to a wrapper function that does the color swapping?

Comment: @romainl Seems like there should be VisualLeave, VisualEnter, SelectEnter, SelectLeave, etc. That would make vim more easily scriptable.

Comment: Agreed, the first thing I tried to write intuitively was: ```àutocmd VisualEnter ...```. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After spending some time in `:help` I ended with the following setup:

```
" Colorize line numbers in insert and visual modes
" ------------------------------------------------
function! SetCursorLineNrColorInsert(mode)
    " Insert mode: blue
    if a:mode == "i"
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=4 guifg=#268bd2

    " Replace mode: red
    elseif a:mode == "r"
        highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=1 guifg=#dc322f

    endif
endfunction


function! SetCursorLineNrColorVisual()
    set updatetime=0

    " Visual mode: orange
    highlight CursorLineNr cterm=none ctermfg=9 guifg=#cb4b16
endfunction


function! ResetCursorLineNrColor()
    set updatetime=4000
    highlight CursorLineNr cterm=none ctermfg=0 guifg=#073642
endfunction


vnoremap <silent> <expr> <SID>SetCursorLineNrColorVisual SetCursorLineNrColorVisual()
nnoremap <silent> <script> v v<SID>SetCursorLineNrColorVisual
nnoremap <silent> <script> V V<SID>SetCursorLineNrColorVisual
nnoremap <silent> <script> <C-v> <C-v><SID>SetCursorLineNrColorVisual


augroup CursorLineNrColorSwap
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * call SetCursorLineNrColorInsert(v:insertmode)
    autocmd InsertLeave * call ResetCursorLineNrColor()
    autocmd CursorHold * call ResetCursorLineNrColor()
augroup END
```

In order to restore the color of line numbers after leaving the visual mode I had to do the following steps:

1. Remap relevant key bindings to call an "enter-visual-function"
2. While entering visual mode the function sets `updatetime=0` for `CursorHold` events
3. Call a "leave-visual-function" by `autocmd CursorHold`
4. While leaving visual mode the function resets `updatetime=4000` for `CursorHold` events

Comment: As a bonus question: When being in visual mode how could I change the line number color of multiple lines according to the current selection? Currently it only changes the color of the current line (where the cursor is placed).

Comment: A couple minor observations after trying this out: 1. I'd recommend adding a `return ''` to the last line of the `SetCursorLineNrColorVisual` function to keep the cursor from jumping the beginning of the current line when entering visual mode. 2. If you add that `return ''` call as I suggested, then before the color updates a key needs to be pressed.  This is a little hacky, but at the end of each `nnoremap` line you can just add `<left><right>`. The color updates because this acts like input, and since it moves the cursor left then right again you shouldn't even notice.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche Thank you! I was trying to fix this behavior on my own for several hours. Hacky solution, but a needed one.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche Change `return ''` to `return 'lh'` seems to resolve this problem as well, as per this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/edkolev/tmuxline.vim/issues/24#issuecomment-447378860).

Answer (score 5):

As romainl has pointed out, there are no events for entering / exiting visual mode. I'd do it like this:

```
function! CursorLineNrColorVisual()
    ...
    return ''   " Return nothing to make the map-expr a no-op.
endfunction
vnoremap <expr> <SID>CursorLineNrColorVisual CursorLineNrColorVisual()
nnoremap <script> v v<SID>CursorLineNrColorVisual
nnoremap <script> V V<SID>CursorLineNrColorVisual
nnoremap <script> <C-v> <C-v><SID>CursorLineNrColorVisual
```

---

Alternatively, you could try putting an expression (`%{CursorLineNrColorVisual}`) into `'statusline'`; this gets evaluated pretty often.

Comment: That's a good approach, but how would I revert the color to its initial value when I return from visual to normal mode by pressing <esc> or <C-c>?

Comment: The same way: `:vnoremap <Esc> ...`. But careful, remapping `<Esc>` can have side effects (hopefully not in visual mode). This still doesn't handle leaving the visual selection when applying a command (e.g. `gU`); for that, the `CursorMoved` / `CursorHold` would be a fallback.

Comment: As you said it has some side effects, e.g. on arrow keys. So it wasn't working out well. After living for a couple of hours in `:help` if found another way to handle all different kinds of leaving the visual mode. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT] Promptlines plugin uses this method :

Since the statusline is re-drawn eachtime a mode is changed, you can have a trigger each time a mode is changed by adding `%{AnyName(mode())}` in your statusline (it will not be displayed). Then, you can implement an `AnyName` function that will be able to filter the current mode.
As an example:

```
let &stl.='%{RedrawStatuslineColors(mode())}'

function! RedrawStatuslineColors(mode)
    if a:mode == 'n'
        call NormalHighlight()
    elseif a:mode == 'i'
        call InsertHighlight()
    elseif a:mode == 'R'
        call ReplaceHighlight()
    elseif a:mode == 'v' || a:mode == 'V' || a:mode == '^V'
        call VisualHighlight()
    endif
endfunction
```

[EDIT 2] [Itchyny](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim/blob/master/autoload/lightline.vim#L346) suggested to use the others methods on this thread, to avoid performances issues: It's advised to cache the mode and finish the function (ie. `RedrawStatuslineColors()`) instantly.