# How to emulate :autocmd VisualLeave * or :autocmd VisualEnter * in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

As you know, there are (sadly) no VisualLeave or VisualEnter autocmds in vim. Is there a way to emulate it?

(Sidenote: Having such events would add even more power to vim)

Comment: It might help if you told us what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger visual mode in vim instantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561132/trigger-visual-mode-in-vim-instantly)

Comment: @IngoKarkat I actually saw that one already. It's just a workaround, and changing the updatetime to 0 won't work in my case because I need it for other things.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash I just want to be able to do something simple like `autocmd VisualLeave * normal <esc>` in an attempt to make the status line, etc, update immediately in console vim (instead of having to press <esc> again or waiting for a timeout). It could be used for other simple things too. Visual[Leave/Enter] would be useful.

Comment: Of course it's a workaround, and you asked for such ("emulate")! If that's not enough, write a patch and submit it to vim_dev; as there are other similar events, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @IngoKarkat True. But that workaround has side effects that affect functionality with other aspects of vim, so it's not a literal emulation. It's more like a workaround that works if you're willing to sacrifice some other functionality elsewhere in vim (in my case, I'd have to change how the vim-signify plugin works to make this workaround work because vim-signify also relies on cursorhold for one of it's features, so that's not what I want to do). Maybe one day I'll have time to make a patch. I feel vim could really use a Visual[Leave|Enter] set of autocmds. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best solution is here: [Run command when vim enters visual mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561132/run-command-when-vim-enters-visual-mode)

It is a workaround to not having the Visual* autocmd events.