# How to automatically remove newline at end of yanked linewise visual selection?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to yank a linewise visual selection without the newline at the end of the last line of the selection? More specifically, I'd like to be able to copy a line or lines from vim to the system clipboard and paste it elsewhere without the last command being executed without a chance to edit it.

I can get the desired effect by executing this command on the register in question after yanking:

```
:let @*=substitute(@*,'\n$','','g')
```

but is there any way to execute that command automatically? I am using MacVim at the moment and there doesn't appear to be a way to map an extra command to <kbd>⌘-C</kbd>, so I'd have to have another mapping to remember to execute after copying if I can't find another solution.

Comment: Instead of doing a visual-line selection you can do just a visual selection

Comment: could you `vnoremap y` to something like `y:NowDoYourSubstituteMagic()` to make that behavior the default?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Indeed, but a linewise selection is generally faster for me. Also, in the case where you select a line then move the cursor up, converting that to a visual selection takes some work.

Answer (score 3):

My original answer to myself has been working well enough that I pretty much forgot about it, but now I've decided to `set clipboard=unnamed` to always yank to the system clipboard. A side effect is that yanking to the clipboard also affects the unnamed register, from which I don't want the trailing newline to be removed.

The new (and more Vim-ish) answer is a mapping to convert the linewise visual selection to characterwise before yanking it:

```
vnoremap <C-c> <Esc>'<0v'>g_y
```

Now I copy with `<C-c>` if I intend to paste in a command line or just `y` any other time. Pretty much what user Explosion Pills suggested but some added stuff to include the first character of the first line and last of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that works for me, inspired by one of the answers here: [Run command when vim enters visual mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561132/run-command-when-vim-enters-visual-mode)

There is no real equivalent to a hypothetical VisualEnter or VisualLeave, but the CursorHold event along with changing `updatetime` will trigger after exiting visual mode. I also added the `gv` map to make it work when copying the previous selection.

```
" Remove last newline after copying visual selection to clipboard
function! RemoveClipboardNewline()
    if &updatetime==1
        let @*=substitute(@*,'\n$','','g')
        set updatetime=4000
    endif
endfunction
function! VisualEnter()
    set updatetime=1
endfunction
vnoremap <expr> <SID>VisualEnter VisualEnter()
nnoremap <script> V V<SID>VisualEnter
nnoremap <script> gv gv<SID>VisualEnter
autocmd CursorHold * call RemoveClipboardNewline()
```

I don't like the idea of writing a swap file every 0 milliseconds, but I tested this in both Windows and OS X, and it works and causes no noticeable performance problems. It doesn't appear to write the swap file unless there are changes.

Also, I'm a little confused as to why this works at all, since it should trigger the function and set `updatetime` back to `4000` while still in visual mode, but apparently the value of `updatetime` doesn't change until after exiting visual mode, which works out nicely here.